# Replace newline (\n) with double backslash n (\\n)

Tags: json, linux, bash, ubuntu

I need to send a string that has newline as a JSON parameter. `\n` causes an error and needs to be encoded as `\\n`.

How can I replace `\n` to `\\n` in pure bash script in linux?

Comment: An example json entry would be helpful. Is \n is a raw string or a newline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
line='\n'
line=${line/\\n/\\\\n}
```

Using quotes might be more readable:

```
r=${line/'\n'/'\\n'}
```

If you want to replace all occurrences, double the first slash:

```
r=${line//'\n'/'\\n'}
#       ^^
```

Comment: This replaces the `n` with `\n`. Needs more backslashes.

Comment: @Wintermute: my bad. Fixed.

Comment: OP probably wants to replace all occurrences. So better use `line=${line//\\n/\\\\n}`

Comment: In the same vein, `${foo//$'\n'/'\\n'}` for literal newlines instead of `\n`. I'm not entirely sure from the question which OP wants. But we're getting there if we aren't already, so 1up.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to replace \n (new line) by \n try this :

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'
```

ex:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'
a\nb\nc
```